# Hypothesis testing for proportions?

Tags: statistics

Here is the following statement:

'A sweet manufacturer selects mints at random from the production line and weighs
them. A random sample of $n_1$ = 194 mints was taken from the day-shift's production,
and a random sample of $n_2$ = 162 mints from the night-shift's production. The number
of these mints which weighed at most 21 grammes was $y_1$ = 28 for the day-shift and
$y_2$ = 11 for the night-shift. Let $p_1$ and $p_2$ denote the proportions of mints that weigh
at most 21 grammes for the day- and night-shifts, respectively.'

I've been told to find a point estimate for $p_1$ and $p_1-p_2$ however I just need clarification whether this relates to hypothesis testing?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Later in the problem set you may be asked a hypothesis testing question about this situation. It is more likely that you will be asked a question that uses the term *confidence interval*.

However, the two problems mentioned are quite simple, and have answers that can be reached without any knowledge of hypothesis testing or confidence intervals.

In this situation, we have two unknown parameters $p_1$ and $p_2$. The question basically asks the following: On the basis of the experimental evidence, what are reasonable estimates of $p_1$ and of $p_1-p_2$?

Comment: so he needs ANOVA analysis right?

Comment: @dato: He needs only arithmetic, and not much of it: we are looking for point estimates.

Comment: On that basis, I'd assume $p_1$ would be equal to 28/194?

Comment: The reasonable *estimate* for $p_1$, based on the sample, is $28/194$. We cannot expect the parameter and the estimate to be the same.

Comment: @SeanyAdams: Got a message notification about confidence interval, but message is not here. For confidence interval for $p_1$, good estimate for the variance of the estimator is $p^\ast(1-p^\ast)/n$, where $p^\ast$ is your point estimate. For the other, variance of the difference is the **sum** of the variances.